# Explain this syntax error in testbench file

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I'm trying to create a testbench file for the sequential circuit in Modelsim (Verilog). But, I'm getting the following syntax error.

> ** Error: (vlog-13069) /Assignment_2x2_tb.v(6): near "initial": syntax error, unexpected initial, expecting ';' or ','.

Here's my code

```
module seq_circuit1_tb;
reg x,clk;
wire q;
seq_circuit1 seqct(x, clk, Q0, Q1)
//Module to generate clock with period 10 time units
initial begin
  forever begin
  clk=0;
  #10
  clk=1;
  #10
  clk=0;
  end
end
initial begin
  x=0;
  #50
  x=0;
  #50
  x=1;
  #50
  x=1;
  #50
end
endmodule
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a semicolon (`;`) after the line `seq_circuit1 seqct(x, clk, Q0, Q1)`.

Comment: Getting new error `near "end": syntax error, unexpected end.` at Line 24 just before `endmodule`.

Comment: `#50` just before `end` seems to be invalid. Maybe you should add `$finish;` or something before the `end`

Answer (score 0):

The initial block cannot end with a delay. You need to have some statement after the last #50 as follows

```
initial begin
  x=0;
  #50
  x=0;
  #50
  x=1;
  #50
  x=1;
  #50 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

or

```
initial begin
  x=0;
  #50
  x=0;
  #50
  x=1;
  #50
  x=1;
  // last #50 removed
end
endmodule
```